# Whats faster? Separate mysql query or array-rearrangement?

Tags: php, mysql, performance, optimization

In many of my scripts I deal with the same results from a mysql query.
I was always wondering if its worth the 'work' just to rearrange my result, so I can iterate through it more comfortably or if I shouldn't bother to make a separate mysql call.

I got four examples, which may result in different answers:

- First I have an array with data from 5 columns. In one function I
  iterate through every single row. In my other function I need only
  one (random) row and only 2 fields of it.
- In another example, I need all rows in both functions, but in one of
  them I need one field as the key in the other one I need only need to
  check for the appearance of a random string/int.
- In my last example I basically need everything from my query for one of my function. The other functions needs only 1 column less.
- And another possibility where I am just wondering whether it would be faster to JOIN one single row from another table and then handle it in php or if I shouldn't bother making a second query for this.

You'll probably say it will depend on the database size, but lets assume I do all these examples in a DB with about 200 rows.

Finally there's to say that I'm aware that I need to code in a way for good readability and however I feel most organized, but this theoretical question just bugs me and I was always wondering whether there is a difference at all and how others handle things like that.

Comment: 10,000 rows is basically NOTHING for a dbms, unless you're running this on a 640k 8088 4.77mhz machine. Ask the question when you're dealing with millions and billions of rows.

Comment: @MarcB: Of course, by then, it'll be too late to refactor.

Comment: errr... are you talking of iterating of all 10000 rows?

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel seeing the problem with big dimensions (re-arranging, iterating) I withdraw the 'big numbers' :)

Comment: and... can you give less vague and more practical examples? what is a random word you are talking about?

Comment: okay okay. I am not of the number itself. I am just wondering is your setup as bad as I suspecting. When you are talking of iterating, are you talking of iterating all the rows in database?

Comment: oh okay. 'random word' was just an example, lets say its an int. keep in mind that its more a general question (hopefully not too broad). about iterating through all the rows, yes sure - how else would you handle say a list of users ?

Comment: it is exact database's purpose to hold a list of users. and it is enrtirely wrong use of database if you are selecting all the rows and then wokring with them in the script.

Comment: Okay, always happy to learn something new, but in which perspective is this wrong when I literally need all the data ? Or how else should I do this then ? I mean, sure I limit the query to a few results per page (pagination like), but that's propably not what you mean.

Comment: that's why I am asking you for the certain example. because "in theory" a database is used to sore the data and to return **only the data required** at the moment.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am suspecting this is a question of the "I have no idea" kind.

It is like "I have my car upside down and I want to know how to drive it faster" question. First of all you have to put it normal way and learn the very basics of driving.

Before asking "which is faster way" one have to ask "which is **proper** way".
And before tagging their question with "optimization" tag one have to have a **certain problem** which needs to be optimized.

As a general rule, database holds all the data as well as doing all the job of **filtering** and **ordering** the data.
So, you have to use SQL commands to retreive required data in the required order.

As a common sense rule, threre is no need to retreive the same data again if you have it already.

I don't know what to answer beside these 2 very basic statements.